# How disable all the clicks excepts particular elements using angular link function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is angular directive link function

```
 function link(WarningService: Warning.Service): ng.IDirectiveLinkFn {
    return ($scope: ng.IScope, element: JQuery): void => {
      element[0].addEventListener('click', () => {

      }, true);
    };
  }
```

I need to enable the click only Button , anchor , input, select,.nav and other item items i dont want clcikc event.

and also avoid click events for disabled elements.i did using jquery below

```
$('body').on('click',function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName !== " 'a' || 'button' || 'input' ||  'select' " 
  || e.target.className == '.nav')
  {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

;

Now i need help how to inclcude my jquery code to my angular directive

```
function link(WarningService: Warning.Service): ng.IDirectiveLinkFn {
    return ($scope: ng.IScope, element: JQuery): void => {
      element[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(element[0].tagName !== " 'a' || 'button' || 'input' ||  'select' " || element[0].className == '.nav')
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                  else{

                  }

      }, true);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try assigning a particular class name to all DOM elements for which you want to disable click event binding . Thus simply check for the class name of the element .

Comment: I am thinking about the same, but vice versa add some class to the elements you want to handle click then select them and attach event handler

Answer (score 0):

First replace that arrow function for click event handler with function.

```
element[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  // here this will refer to your element[0]
  // and then check if this has the class you're looking for or
  // tag name you're looking for
}, true);
```

Comment: How I need to pass event inside my link function?

Comment: The same way you'd do it `element[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){`

Comment: and you don't need to pass event to your link function. It will be passed implicitly as you've bound click event handler to `element[0]` using `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class in top level DOM (body) say `disableOthers` and maintain a css like

```
.disableOthers *:not(button):not(a):not(button):not(select):not(nav) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and just add/remove the class pragmatically in top level hierarchy.